# Как правильно вызывать РАЗНЫЕ методы контроллера из JSP?

Tags: servlet, mvc, jsp

Здравствуйте.

Ситуация такая. Есть JSP страница. На ней две формы:

```
    <form method="post">
         <input type="text" name="addName">
         <button type="SUBMIT">Add</button>
    </form>
    <form method="post">
         <input type="text" name="deleteName">
         <button type="SUBMIT">Delete</button>
    </form>
```

Суть вопроса в следующем: мне хотелось бы как-то напрямую задействовать мои методы из контроллера, к примеру, названия методов:

```
    public void add(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp);
    public void delete(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp);
```

В Liferay, к примеру, у aui:form в параметр name записывается название метода контроллера, который будет выполнятся по Submit form. Как правильно обратиться к методам контроллера в моем случае?

Comment: @WildCherryCandy, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Например, в сервлете:

```
        smb1 = request.getParameter("addName");
        if (smb1 == null)
            <blah-blah-blah>
        else
            add(request, response);
```